# Auctions System Logical Condition

Tags: conditional-statements, logical-operators

I am trying to make an auctions system but can not figure out the logical conditions for doing so..

Lets say that I have 10 credit 
`$credit`

I have already bet 5 credits on another auction... so I owe 5 from 10 `$owe`

I thus have 5 available... `$available = $credit - $owe (=5)`

I bet 3 from available (on a different item)...
I wish to bet again 4 (cancel 3, update to 4), but credit available is now `$available - 3 (=2)`
Can't find a logical solution.... written in code.
What is the condition for setting a bet???

Made up a matrix with the dependence between variables:

```
 bet  available    owe    lastbet  
 1       10        10       0     
 2       9         11       1     
 3       7         13       2     
 4       4         16       3     
 5       0         20       4
 6      -5         25       5
 7     -11         31       6
 8     -18         38       7
 9     -26         46       8
10     -35         55       9
11     -45         65       10
```

Need to translate it into a condition statement.... (the next row would not meet the conditions)

The condition should fail on the 11th row....

Answer (score 0):

Based on the Matrix... I found out that the condition is:

if ($bet <= (($owe + $available) / 2)) {}

Not very intuitive......